# Selenium logging in Java - best practice?

Tags: java, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver

What are the current best practices for logging selenium webdriver activity?

Are there any out-of-the-box tools that hook in to native webdriver actions?

I am interested in what specific tools you have used, what helpful references you might have, and what evidence you might have to justify your assessment of the current state-of-the-art of web automation logging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LoggingPreferences` class is a native `Selenium` class available in Java binding for logging. See doc [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingPreferences.html). It does give you the option for logging in different level of activities and events. Also, see [Logs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/logging/Logs.html) interface